# Alternative for deprecated CreateImage function in cv2 API

Tags: python, opencv

I am updating the packages used in a project of mine and I would like to use the updated cv2 API and I've come across this problem where the cv.CreateImage function is no longer being used.

The following is the code that is giving me problems:

```py
grey_image = cv.cvtColor(i, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
df_dx = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(i), cv.IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1)
cv.Sobel(grey_image, df_dx, 1, 1)
```

The variable 'i' is an RGB image of size 640*480.

I've tried to make use of numpy to replicate what this method should be doing as follows:

```py
df_dx = np.zeros(i.shape[0], i.shape[1], i.shape[2]), np.int16)
```

but this then provides the following errors

```py
<class 'tuple'>: (<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError('only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars'), None)
```

This forced me to believe that when i'm creating the numpy array, it is throwing this error, and i do not know how I can fix it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Third parameter to `cv.CreateImage` is `1`, hence `df_dx` should only have 1 channel, not the same number of channels as `i`. In other words... `np.zeros(i.shape[0], i.shape[1]), np.int16)`

Comment: It seemed the error was the documentation not being as clear as it should have been. I could bypass the creation of the image as the updated Sobel function returns an image which in this case would be the df_dx variable